# Get different attributes of a single TEI-Tags with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, attributes, tei

i have an xml-code (TEI) like this:

```
    <pb n="19"/> <lb n="1"/><rs type="author" xml:id="MH"><rs type="patient" xml:id="BavoilMr">Mr. Bavoil</rs> - 56 ans - clincailler au quai au<supplied reason="omitted">x</supplied> fleur<supplied reason="omitted">s</supplied> - <lb n="2"/>100 toujours l'ouïe dure <lb n="3"/>26 mai<note>"mai" korrigiert aus "mars".</note>- l'oreille droite jette du pus depuis 6 ou 8 mois - ce mois<supplied reason="omitted">-</supplied> <lb n="4"/>ci encore plus
- surdité de cette oreille depuis 2 mois <lb n="5"/>il a eu un coup d'air en route - depuis 15 ans il a eu <lb n="6"/>l'oreille dure alternativement l'une et l'autre - <lb n="7"/>maintenant alternativement aussi <lb n="8"/>douleur <del rend="crossout">dans</del> sur l'os externe du coude il ne peut rien lever en
```

and want to translate it into an html file where the RS-Tag `<rs type="author" xml:id="MH"> ... </rs>` is an anchor like that `<a id=MH"> ... </a>`

My XSL-Code can translat one rs-tag with a special attribute:

```
<xsl:template match= "//tei:rs[@xml:id='MH']">
        <a id="MH">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
```

but i can not iterate through all the rs-tags to get all the xml:id's as an attribute and write it as an id in the `<a id="MH">`

like:

```
<a id="Bavoil"> ... </a>
<a id="xml_id_of_person2> ... </a>
<a id="xml_id_of_person3"> ... </a>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are matching only nodes having a value of `MH` in attribute `xml:id`. If you match the `<rs>` tag having non-empty `xml:id` attribute, you should be able to get the list.

Comment: i want the  the attribute. How would i get it, if i match only the rs take? could give me a short code?

Comment: Added sample code snippet for XML, XSLT and its output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match all the `<rs>` nodes having `@id` attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="rs[@id]">
```

**Sample XML**

```
<root>
    <rs type="author" id="MH"></rs>
    <rs type="patient" id="BavoilMr"></rs>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="rs[@id]">
        <a id="{@id}"></a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<a id="MH"/>
<a id="BavoilMr"/>
```

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer and it's benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)